# How do you add an item to a list that is equivalent to the value of the previous item + 1 in vb.net

Tags: list, vb.net, formatting

so i want to make a list of items from 2 onward updating every timer tic and i dont know how.
declaring a variable with the name "all(n)", with n being the value of a variable that updates + 1 every tic works too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Class that uses a [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer) to add a new item to a [List(of Integer)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) every time the timer elapses, adding 1 to the previous value in the list:

```
Public Class TimerList

    Private WithEvents _timer As New System.Timers.Timer
    Private _list As New List(Of Integer)

    Public Event ListUpdated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Public Sub New()
        With _timer
            .Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).TotalMilliseconds
            .AutoReset = True
            .Enabled = True
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub _timer_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs) Handles _timer.Elapsed
        If _list.Count = 0 Then
            ' First value is 2
            _list.Add(2)
        Else
            Dim previousValue As Integer = _list.Item(_list.Count - 1)
            _list.Add(previousValue + 1)
        End If
        RaiseEvent ListUpdated(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property List() As List(Of Integer)
        Get
            Return _list
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: i have no idea what any of that is or does but thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer control and a global variable to store the data.

```
 public class TimerExample
 Private Shared WithEvents myTimer As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer()
    Private Shared timecounter As Integer = 2
private _list as new list(of Integer)

Private Shared Sub TimerEventProcessor(myObject As Object, _
                                           ByVal myEventArgs As EventArgs) _
                                       Handles myTimer.Tick
if timecounter=100 then
    mytimer.stop
else
   _list.add(timecounter)
   timecounter+=1
endif
    End Sub
end class
```